# Creating Package feed in Octopus Deploy

Tags: c#, tfs, octopus-deploy

I am new to using octopus deploy. I am publishing nuget packages from tfs build to local storage. Is there any way Octopus server can check regularly the publishing folder, and if new version/new file is found, it will deploy it to the deployment environment.

PS:- I was thinking to create a package feed for local storage but couldn't find any link describing the same.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octopus can automatically trigger deployments when new packages are pushed to the built-in repository, but not to external repositories.

Your options are:

1. Enable [Automatic Release Creation](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Automatic+Release+Creation), and make sure your Project's [Lifecycle](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Lifecycles) automatically deploys to your first environment. You'll need to push your package to the built-in server rather than use the filesystem. You can do this fairly easily either with [nuget.exe](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#push-command) or [octo.exe](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Pushing+packages).
2. As the last step of your build, manually create a Release using either the [VSTS/TFS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octopusdeploy.octopus-deploy-build-release-tasks), the [Octopus REST API](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Octopus+REST+API), or [octo.exe](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Creating+releases). By default, this will use the newest package it can find (which should be the one you just packed). If your Lifecycle doesn't automatically deploy to an environment, you can deploy the Release the same way.

Comment: Enable Automatic Release Creation not working. The package got pushed to the repo but automatic release is not being triggered. Tried deleting the entire project and recreating it in octopus deploy and again adding the process step to deploy the package. Manually, its working, but not the automatically release.

Comment: @Leo - There could be several reasons for that... The package version number must be the latest, you must be using the built-in feed, and you need to enable ARC for the project, pointing at the step that uses that package. If those are all true, I'd suggest writing to support@octopus.com for more help.

Comment: The setup is same as described by you. I guess will have to contact Octopus support for this.

Comment: Have you turned on automatic release creation from your Octopus project settings page? Can you update your post with some screenshots??

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a deployment, you need to create a release - the server won't poll a package feed and trigger a release.

I would suggest publishing the packages to the Octopus Deploy server and creating a release. You can setup a lifecycle on the project to automatically deploy to the initial environment once a release is created if you wish.

The following links would be worth reading.

[Team Foundation Server Integration](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3048175)

[Team Foundation Build Custom Task](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Use+the+Team+Foundation+Build+Custom+Task)

[Lifecycles](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Lifecycles)

Hope this helps

Comment: The 1st link worked for me. Actually, the problem(more of a silly mistake) was with the API-key. I didn't set-up a new api-key. But now got it working